# Google + API Backward Compatiblity

Tags: api, google-app-engine, sign, google-signin

We were using Google + API for Sign in. It has started throwing the error below. Pet Google enabling the below service should solve the issue - but in Google Console - It doesn’t even allow to do it; it says loading error?

Any suggestion will be helpful. The Login is not working and its a BLOCKER for customers.

Issue explained in below:

> Ooophs, we got an error: User profile request failed! Google returned an invalid response:stdClass::__set_state(array( 'error' => stdClass::__set_state(array( 'code' => 403, 'message' => 'Legacy People API has not been used in project ******** before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/legacypeople.googleapis.com/overview?project=****** then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.', 'status' => 'PERMISSION_DENIED', 'details' => array ( 0 => stdClass::__set_state(array( '@type' => 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help', 'links' => array ( 0 => stdClass::__set_state(array( 'description' => 'Google developers console API activation', 'url' => 'https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/legacypeople.googleapis.com/overview?project=**********', )), ), )), ), )), ))

Comment: Hi @Mohit Mohan, is your issue still there? Were you able to enable de API thourgh clicking the link?

Comment: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/legacypeople.googleapis.com/overview?project=******  link doesnt even open - it says loading error.

Comment: This is a like deadlock situation!!

Answer (score 0):

I just found [this documentation about the API](https://developers.google.com/people/legacy#overview), and there is a Warning:

> Warning: The Legacy People API cannot be manually re-enabled for a developer project after it has been disabled. Developers should migrate fully to replacements such as Google Sign-in or Google People API before disabling the Legacy People API.

Have you tried this?

Comment: Not sure which API to search for when they say Legacy People API. Google + API is enabled for my project.